# I am using Window Server 2008 VPS, how to make that when user type the IP address it will go to Tomcat page not IIS page?

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, iis

I have just bought Godaddy Virtual Private Server plan with Window Server 2008.

I can login VPS Server via Remote Desktop Connection. Each VPS has an IPaddress. when user types my idaddress x.x.x.x it will show the default IIS7 page like this:
[image]

Ok, now I downloaded Tomcat7, JRE6 & can be able to see tomcat page at `http://localhost:8080/` or `x.x.x.x:8080`. Now I want that when typing my idaddress x.x.x.x it will show the default Tomcat page rather than IIS7 page.

So here is what I did. I edited `C:\tomcat7\conf\server.xml`

```
  <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" /> //changed port from 8080 to 80
```

Ok, now when entered `x.x.x.x:8080` it showed `Unable to connect`, when entered `x.x.x.x` it still shows the IIS7 page.

How to config so that when user types my idaddress x.x.x.x it will show the default Tomcat page rather than IIS7 page?

Extra info: Now I have just turned off `World Wide Publishing service` in WindowServer, & I expected that when entered `x.x.x.x` it will show the Tomcat default page but it showed nothing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did, so simple just turn off `World Wide Publishing service` in WindowServer & then change port 8080 in `C:\tomcat7\conf\server.xml` to 80 & now when typing ipaddress it showed tomcat default page